# How can I use the selectedValue from the dropdown to then call an API using it and render the JSON?

Tags: reactjs

I have to create a dropdown with 3-4 options and based on the value selected by the user, I have to then call an API using the selected Value as the search string. The JSON returned from this API should then render as a DataGrid in the mainContent section of the page.

This is how the dropdown looks like, pretty basic:

```
 handleDropdownChange(e) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: e.target.value});
  }

render() {

   <div>
      <select id="dropdown" onChange={this.handleDropdownChange} className={classes.mainContent}>
                <option value="">select</option>
                <option value="option1">1</option>
                <option value="Option2">2</option>
                <option value="Option3">3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

And I can then do:

```
<div>Selected value is : {this.state.selectedValue}</div>
```

This works!

But instead of the above, I want to use a function something-like:

```
 grabData = () => {
   fetch(API + {this.state.selectedValue})
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('something is wrong');
        }
      })
      .then (data => this.setState({ myhits: data.hits, hitsIndex: 0, isLoading: false }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
 }
```

so, inside the render() I want to basically do- (see that I want to use the selectedValue in the function grabData above):

```
<div>
   Selected value is : {this.grabData}
</div>
```

I'm open to suggestions on how best to do this. This is what I could think of, but it doesn't work.
Or, even better if someone can help me render that JSON in a datagrid.
I hope I haven't confused everyone :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the second approach cause `grabData()` is calling `setState` when promise resolves/rejects.

Comment: grabData() is calling setState to get the json data from the API into myhits array. I can then use myhits to render. But its not allowing me the fetch(API + {this.state.selectedValue})

Comment: Can you check the console if there are any errors? If yes, post them so we can get a better insight into your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to run `grabData`, when the user changed the value, then call this function on change.
change this function:

```
handleDropdownChange(e) {
   this.setState({selectedValue: e.target.value}, () => {
      // Once the state is updated - call grabData...
      this.grabData()
   });
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it throws up:

./src/App.js
  Line 83:  Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'

  81 | 
  82 |  grabData = () => {
> 83 |    fetch(API + {this.state.selectedValue})

Comment: Why do you even need to set it to state if the value of the event objects changes dynamically? You can just make the API call using `e.target.value` without using the setState callback and improving performance.

Comment: Correct @RohitKashyap that would be unncessary to first setState and then use it later. One step less. Thanks for that tip.
Can you guys@Gugu  help with the this.grabData() not actually working correctly. How can I make it fetch the API, and render the output for each dropdown selection? I'm struggling to supply the selectedValue to the this.grabData() for it to run and to make it run on each selection change. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I marked Gugu's answer as accepted as it did work eventually :-) Thanks bud.

So, I got this to work. This is how:

This is how my dropdown looks like. See I added the grabData() inside my handleDropdownChange():

```
handleDropdownChange(e) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: e.target.value});
       this.grabData()
  }

grabData = (selectedValue) => {
  fetch(API + {selectedValue})
        .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('something is wrong');
        }
      })
      .then (data => this.setState({ selectedData: data.hits, selectedIndex: 0, isLoading: false }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
 }
```

And then in the render() I added a map for the data:

```
render() {

   <div>
      <select id="dropdown" onChange={this.handleDropdownChange} className={classes.mainContent}>
                <option value="">select</option>
                <option value="option1">1</option>
                <option value="Option2">2</option>
                <option value="Option3">3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div>
        <ThemeProvider theme={LIGHT_THEME}>
            {
              selectedData.map(hit =>
                <ThemeProvider theme={DARK_THEME}>
                <div key={hit.objectID}>
                  <button> {hit.created_at} {hit.url}</button>
                </div>
                </ThemeProvider>
            )}
        </ThemeProvider>
   </div>
```

I just need to figure out how to render on each click. Right now, it renders on the first selection and doesn't render fresh results if I change the selection.

Comment: Start using on your render function the new stated that you just recieved. `const { selectedData } = this.state` And use it, once a new data arrived, it should change :)

Comment: @Gugu Thanks. Actually, I need to input the selectedValue to my grabData() function for the API fetch and then use that data in the render().  This is where I am having issues. If, however, instead of calling grabData() inside handleDropdownChange() I just copy the grabData() into it, it works ok. But I don't want to do it that way. I want to call the grabData(), but that is not wokring as it should. Any ideas?

Can I do something like this in grabData():
```
grabData = () = {
  const {selectedValue} = this.state,
  fetch (API + {selectedValue}
     .then(response => {
      ...
```

Comment: i didn't get your example. sorry. Check out this example: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html. it's streight forward

Comment: I get that example, pretty simple & straightforward. But I'm trying to go one step more: 1. I want the user to select a value from the dropdown, 2. use onChange to catch the selectedItem 3. then using the selectedItem I want to make an API call. Right now, I can't get the onChange to work in sense that I get this when the user selects a value from the dropdown: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
TaskSideBar.handleDropdownChange
src/TaskSidebar.js:86
  83 | 
  84 | 
  85 | handleDropdownChange(e) {
> 86 |   this.setState({selectedItem: e.target.value})
Makes sense?